# Node.js Running in a directory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ip, port

Currently, I have all my node.js files in the following directory:

- mydomain.com

  - f1

    - f2

      - index.js

When I start using `node index.js` the program runs on `mydomain.com:8080`, but I was wondering if it would be possible to run on `mydomain.com/f1/f2` ?

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Anything is possible, but Node isn't really mapped to folders at all, so why would you want to do that ?

Comment: Hmm.. What you're looking for is the idea of routes. I would recommend looking up what `Express.js` is and how to use it. Here's a tutorial link that might help a little (http://webapplog.com/url-parameters-and-routing-in-express-js/)

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with express js which is a framework of nodejs
Try reading about **express js** and **Routes** in it.it will be helpful